# VBA Modify Insert Date Macro

Tags: excel, vba

There's a lot I like about this script I use to auto-insert the date into next cell over from where I input a value, but I would like if it didn't change a date that already existed.

When I input the initials of whoever finished a job into a cell in range T3:T5003, the date is automatically inserted in the adjacent cell in range U3:U5003. The problem is that I might have to change or modify the entries in T3:T5003 at a later date, but I don't want the original date to change. So I just want this auto-inserting to work only when there is nothing in the adjacent cell.

Here's the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
With Target
    If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Range("T3:T5003"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Activate
            Else
                With .Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Date
                End With
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried other scripts that didn't write over an existing date, but they had other problems, and they were difficult for me to understand how they work, so I'm hoping that we can just modify the one I'm using. But I will take anything that works and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you using `Activate` in a `Worksheet_Change` event? That would annoy me to no end as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to an IF checking if the cell to the right is empty or not:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
With Target
    If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:A100"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Activate
            Else
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "" Then
                    With .Offset(0, 1)
                        .Value = Date
                    End With
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Michal! O.PAL's works great too and that's what I'm probably going to use, but you kept most of my code intact, which is what I originally asked, so technically you answered the most correctly. I wish I could checkmark both. I really do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range("T3:T5003"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            If IsEmpty(.Offset(0, 1)) Then .Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you O.PAL! I'm torn on who's answer to checkmark. I am using your code because I love that it is way simpler than what I started out with, however, Michal actually answered more correctly to how I asked the question by keeping the original code intact - which after seeing your code, I realize that wasn't necessary. I feel terrible that I can't checkmark both answers. But what I learned is that I need to ask questions in a manner that's more open to answers. I appreciate your help very much!